# error on st_intersects

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have this query where I'm trying to two join tables with st_intersects. There will be different geometry types in the `workarea` column but the `point_geom` will always be a point.

```
with cte1 as (
          select t.number, 
             upper(t.workstreetname) as workstreetname, 
                     upper(t.workcounty) as workcounty, 
                     upper(t.workplace) as workplace, 
                     upper(t.workarea) as workarea
          from schema.ticket t 
              )
cte2 as (select distinct number, workstreetname, workcounty, workplace, workarea from cte1)
select c.number,
       c.workarea as workarea,
       a.geom as point_geom,
from cte2 c
join schema.addresses a on st_intersects(a.geom,c.workarea);
```

But I am confusing it somewhere because I get this error:

```
ERROR:  function st_intersects(geometry, text) is not unique
LINE 27: join schema.addresses a on st_intersects(a.geom,c.wo...
                                    ^
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
********** Error **********

ERROR: function st_intersects(geometry, text) is not unique
SQL state: 42725
Hint: Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 1246
```

Any suggestions on where I am going wrong on this?

Comment: is workarea a geometry? looks like c.workarea is text

Comment: yes, there will be multiple types of geom in that column.

Comment: `upper(t.workarea) as workarea` this is text, also the error tells you the second input for the st_intersects function is text..

Comment: you are right @ziggy

Comment: @ziggy write an answer from your comment...let's follow the efforts to have less 'unanswered/answered in comments' questions on this board (I need to improve on that myself) ,)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first CTE, `upper(t.workarea) as workarea` is a text field. later when calling `st_intersects(a.geom,c.workarea)`, that same workarea text field is used as the second input for the `st_intersects` function which gives the insightful error. Make sure both inputs are geometries